# Play! framework renderJson not exposing particular fields

Tags: java, json, annotations, playframework, gson

I'm trying to expose a dynamic(transient) field in my models via renderJson(), but it's not working. Here's an example:

```
@Entity
public class Room extends Model {

  public String name;
  public String code;
  @Transient
  public List<Booking> bookings;

  @Transient
  @Expose
  public String resource_uri;

  public Room(String name, String code) {
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
  }

  public List<Booking> getBookings() {
    return Booking.find("byRoom", this).fetch();
  }

  public String getResource_uri(){
    return "/api/room/" + this.id; //the uri is evaluated dynamically.
  }
```

A call to *renderJson(Room.findById(2))* renders this as a response:

```
{"name":"Room B","code":"R-B","id":2}
```

The resource_uri field is missing. The @Expose annotation seems to do nothing. And I can't view renderJson's declaration since the framework generates all the code by annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play! uses Gson. It doesn´t serialize transient fields.

Take a look at https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples

I like Gson because it comes with Play! out of the box.
You can build your own, adapter, something like:

```
public class RoomAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Room>, JsonSerializer<Room> {
    public Room deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context){
        // Parse the Json to build a Room
    }

    public JsonElement serialize(Room room, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context){
        // Insert magic here!!
    }
}
```

Register the serializer:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(
            Room.class, new RoomAdapter()).create();
```

And use the gson specifying the class you want to serialize:

```
String jsonRoom = gson.toJson(aRoom, Room.class);
Room aRoom = gson.fromJson(jsonRoom, Room.class);
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it serialize transient fields? the resource_uri is not really something I want persisted to the database as it is merely meta-data used for the REST interface.

Comment: Upon further digging, I've discovered that Gson cannot serialize properties. At all. It's because it uses reflection to find the fields, apparently. 

What alternatives can I look at that has this functionality? FlexJSON?

Comment: You can do it with Gson, I've posted an example of a custom adapter in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a discrepancy in your field declarations, you have

```
@Transient
@Expose
public String resource_uri;
```

Yet, you also have

```
public String getResource_uri(){
   return "/api/room/" + this.id; //the uri is evaluated dynamically.
}
```

This would suggest that your resource_uri field is forever null?

Comment: But it isn't null, it shows up in terminal when I *System.out.println(u.resource_uri);*.
It shows up as "/api/room/2" I can see how my comment can be confusing though, "the uri is evaluated dynamically" as opposed to being retrieved directly as a persistent ORM field.

Answer (score 1):

Play framework 2.0 uses jackson to make a json string. Use @JsonIgnore annotation on the fields, that you do not want to expose